# GCloud Vision - Bad results for node api compare to the Vision landing page demo

Tags: node.js, image-processing, gcloud, vision, gcloud-node

I'm using the `gcloud` Node SDK to detect text in small images.
It works ok for most of the samples but then, there are a couple of rather obvious image samples that somehow *GCloud fails to read*.

However when i try the exact image on Vision landing page [GCloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) it works just perfectly.

```
    const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision')
    vision.detectText('my-image.jpg').then((result) => {
       // result is empty
    });
```

Sample Image:

[image]

Gcloud Node SDK Result (EMPTY):

```
[[],{"responses":[{"faceAnnotations":[],"landmarkAnnotations":[],"logoAnnotations":[],"labelAnnotations":[],"textAnnotations":[],"fullTextAnnotation":null,"safeSearchAnnotation":null,"imagePropertiesAnnotation":null,"cropHintsAnnotation":null,"webDetection":null,"error":null}]}]
```

GCloud Vision Landing page demo result (CORRECT) :

[image]

Comment: I'm using the png file that you shared and I don't get any `Text` results on the landing page. Did you use a different file format when you first tried it?